# Smarty Modifier - Turn urls into links

Tags: php, smarty, modifiers

Is there a smarty modifier that will add anchor tags to links. 
eg

```
$smarty->assign('mytext','This is my text with a http://www.link.com');

{$mytext|link}
```

which will display,

```
This is my text with a <a href='http://www.link.com'>http://www.link.com</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created this modifier, seems to work pretty well. I think the biggest improvement could be to the regex.

```
<?php
/**
 * Smarty plugin
 * @package Smarty
 * @subpackage PluginsModifier
 */

/**
 * Smarty link_urls plugin 
 * 
 * Type:     modifier<br>
 * Name:     link_urls<br>
 * Purpose:  performs a regex and replaces any url's with links containing themselves as the text
 * This could be improved by using a better regex.
 * And maybe it would be better for usability if the http:// was cut off the front?
 * @author Andrew
 * @return string 
 */

function smarty_modifier_link_urls($string)
{
    $linkedString = preg_replace_callback("/\b(https?):\/\/([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]*)\b/i",
                                create_function(
                                '$matches',
                                'return "<a href=\'".($matches[0])."\'>".($matches[0])."</a>";'
                                ),$string);

    return $linkedString;
} 

?>
```

Comment: You can just return the value directly from the `preg_replace_callback` function, this will save you setting an extra variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution its works for all URLS (https, http and www)

```
{$customer.description|regex_replace:" @((([[:alnum:]]+)://|www\.)([^[:space:]]*)([[:alnum:]#?/&=]))@":
 " <a href=\"\\1\" target=\"_blank\" >\\1</a>"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use Smarty Variable Modifier "regex_replace":

```
{$variable|regex_replace:"/\b((https?):\/\/([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]*))\b/i":"<a href='$1' target='_blank'>$3</a>"}
```

Answer (score -3):

You will have to write a plugin.

http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/